# PHP code modification to retrieve only the first image to add to PDF

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

The following PHP code gets all the images for a product from the database to display in a pdf document. How do we have it only get the first image, and ignore the rest, to add to the pdf document. TIA

```
// Adding Pages for Images
$sql="select * from es_pro_pic where prod_id=$id and type='images' and  active='yes' and del='no'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    while($rs=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $logoFile = "picture/" . $rs['pic'];
        $logoXPos = 10;
        $logoYPos = 30;
        $logoWidth = 190; // 2480
        $logoHeight = ''; // 3508

        $pdf->AddPage();
        // Set PDF Cut Sheets
        $pdf->SetTextColor($c_grey);
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 14);
        $pdf->Write(15, "Product Images: ");
        $pdf->Ln(20);
        $pdf->Image( $logoFile, $logoXPos, $logoYPos, $logoWidth );
    }
}
```

Comment: What would happen if you eliminated the WHILE loop (Which isn't properly {} delimited, missinging open bracket) and just processed once?

Comment: I copied it wrong. that's why it was missing an opening { under the while line. I tried removing the while, so I had: `code`($rs=mysql_fetch_array($result))
       `code`{ `code`$logoFile = "picture/" . $rs['pic'];...   Should I get rid of the { and }?     I corrected the { above. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a `LIMIT 1` to your sql query like that

```
$sql="select * from es_pro_pic where prod_id=$id and type='images' and  active='yes' and del='no' LIMIT 1";
```

This would return only the first row.